# Is There Powdery Mildew On My Lily Plants?

Tags: diagnosis, plant-care, lily, mildew

Recently, there was a large rainstorm in my area, which soaked my lilies’ leaves thoroughly. Afterwards, and even for a while before then, I had noticed small white dots on their leaves.

If this is powdery mildew, what should I do about it? I’m hesitant to use milk and water on them, since it seems like water would only make the problem worse, but I’ve heard that neem oil works well. Might it also help to move them into a shallower pot (the one I have is pretty deep)?

[image]

Comment: a closeup picture would really help...

Comment: Hi! You were unable to leave this as a comment because you have a couple of unregistered user accounts. Please consider [registering](/help/why-register) one of them then [merge them](/help/merging-accounts) together, which will allow you to [edit](/help/privileges/create-posts), [comment on](/help/privileges/comment) any of your posts and [accept an answer](/help/someone-answers) on your question. Thanks, and welcome to the site!

Comment: @kevinsky Okay, here you go. https://i.stack.imgur.com/LAJ10.jpg